# Getting a value from a class using a return statement within the class

Tags: python, pycharm

```
class Player1:
    base_HP = 300

    def getBHP(self):
        return self.base_HP


jogador1 = Player1
jogador1_hp = jogador1.getBHP() #Functions and Class calls must end with brackets.


print(jogador1_hp)
```

That's the code I'm using to get the player HP and i want to save it at jogador1_hp.

How ever this is what iam getting:

```
C:\Users\joaol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe C:/Users/joaol/PycharmProjects/FirstProgram/Main.py
<function Player1.getBHP at 0x02C131E0>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Even if i do as below, I'm still getting a blank console.

```
class Player1:
    base_HP = 300

    def getBHP(self):
        print(self.base_HP)


jogador1 = Player1
jogador1.getBHP
```

EDIT: I fix it ,i just needed to add "()" when i create the object!

```
jogador1 = Player1()
jogador1_hp = jogador1.getBHP()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call methods for them to execute.

```
jogador1_hp = jogador1.getBHP()
```

Answer (score 0):

If i use jogador1_hp = jogador1.getBHP() i get this :

```
C:\Users\joaol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe C:/Users/joaol/PycharmProjects/FirstProgram/Main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/joaol/PycharmProjects/FirstProgram/Main.py", line 19, in <module>
    jogador1_hp = jogador1.getBHP()
TypeError: getBHP() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't instantiate the `Player1` class. In your code, `jogador1` is just another name for the `Player1` class. You should call the class to instantiate it, like: `jogador1 = Player1()`